# how to disable some views from rotation for xcode 6.1

Tags: objective-c, iphone, xcode, ipad, rotation

I am trying to get some screens not to rotate on some views of my app but I can't seem to do it. Some views shouldn't rotate and I have been looking around and see that the code might now be deprecated but I need this not to rotate.

Currently my view still rotates with this code:

```
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate{
return  NO;
}

-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations{
return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}

-(UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation{
return UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: There are many duplicates of this question. Note that it's not the version of XCode that matters so much as the target version of iOS. (Versions before 6.0 were particularly different.) Bottom line, you may find it very hard to have only SOME views of your app autorotate and not others, UNLESS the ones that rotate are modal (presented) viewControllers.